# Getting Unique rows from SQl using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, lambda

I have below table structure. I'm trying to figure out how to get total number of unique rows using the TransactionId column.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYB0D.jpg)

Could some please help me on how to get unique rows using the TransactionId column.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I should get total number of orders. that means I should get count as 4, but i'm getting as 5.

Comment: Why do you need to use a lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(distinct case when right(transactionid, 2) like '-[0-9]'
                      then left(transactionid, len(transactionid) - 2) --cut out the version (-1,-2,-3,etc.)
                      else transactionid end
        ) [NumberOfUniqueTransactionId]
from MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks Michal!. But problem here is for Some transactions we will add -1 or -2 based on service type but for others we will not add. Now when i'm trying to fetch total number of orders based on transactionId I'm getting more count. for example in the above image I have below transactions 128654-3d55667-1
128654-3d55667-2
133456
458645
127976-3d55667-1. First and Second transactiond's are same, but based on service we have added -1 and -2 but for 3 and 4th transactions we didn't add. So now when I fetch I should get total count as 4. But i'm getting 5.

Answer (score 0):

you must use distinct

```
 select distinct  left(TransactionId,LEN(TransactionId)-CHARINDEX('-',TransactionId)) from yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks Mehdi!. But problem here is for Some transactions we will add -1 or -2 based on service type but for others we will not add. Now when i'm trying to fetch total number of orders based on transactionId I'm getting more count. for example in the above image I have below transactions 128654-3d55667-1
128654-3d55667-2
133456
458645
127976-3d55667-1. first and second transactiond's are same. but based on service we have added -1 and -2 but for 3 and 4th transactions we didn't add.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you using Linq To SQL or entity framework to query your SQL (assuming because you mentioned about using C# lambda expression)

Let say your poco entity looks like :

```
public class Entity
    {
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        public string ServiceId { get; set; }
        public string SourceApplicationName { get; set; }
    }
```

You can use below query :

```
List<Entity> entities = null; /* you might want to use it from DB context */
var result = entities.DistinctBy(e => new { e.TransactionId, e.ServiceId, e.SourceApplicationName });
```

Since DistinctBy is not available as extension method. You can have one generic extension method like below :

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
        {
            HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
            foreach (TSource element in source)
            {
                if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                {
                    yield return element;
                }
            }
        }
```